# C# Bundles not working on my server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, bundle

I know there are a lot of topics about this subject but I think I've already read them all. As I'm still not able to fix my issue I write my own topic.

Here is my BundleConfig file :

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/layoutJS")
        .Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"
            , "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"
            , "~/Scripts/jquery.stellar.js"
            , "~/Scripts/jquery.velocity.js"
            , "~/Scripts/jquery.tubular.1.0.custom.js"
            , "~/Scripts/helper.js"
            , "~/Scripts/Style/Plugins/popup.js"
            , "~/Scripts/Style/Plugins/select.js"
            , "~/Scripts/Style/Plugins/jQuery/cnil.js"
            , "~/Scripts/Style/layout.js"
        );

    scriptBundle.Orderer = new BundleOrderer();
    bundles.Add(scriptBundle);

    var cssBundle = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/layoutCSS")
        .Include(
            "~/Content/Style/Font-Awesome/font-awesome.css"
            , "~/Content/Style/Jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css"
            , "~/Content/Style/Jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.css"
            , "~/Content/Style/Jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css"
        );
    cssBundle.Orderer = new BundleOrderer();
    bundles.Add(cssBundle);
}
```

I don't have this line :

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Because I have **web.config** which do the trick. Here is a part of my web.config (used localy only)

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

And here is the **web.release.config** used for my stage server :

```
<system.web xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="false"/>
</system.web>
```

Finaly in my **_layout.cshtml** I render my bundles like that :

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/layoutCSS")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/layoutJS")
```

So I think I'm alright but... Not :( If I run my website on local, either it's on debug or release configuration, the behavior is ok, all my scripts and styles are presents and there are no errors in the chrome console.

But when I'm deploying on my server... It's broken :
- First I don't have version number on bundles in the source code
- Second obviously I have a 404 for each bundles...

Is there something to do on my server's IIS ?
Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot for your futur answers !

EDIT : Registration of bundles :

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Bootstraper.Run();

    var unitOfWork = (IUnitOfWork)Bootstraper.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
    var cache = (ICacheManager) Bootstraper.GetInstance<ICacheManager>();

    MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes, unitOfWork.RouteRepository, cache);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the call to `RegisterBundles` and surrounding? Also have you tried to run your website in release locally?

Comment: Yes sure, I've edited my post with it at the end.
And yes i've tested that... And it works :(

Comment: What is the OS and the IIS version on your server? What version of MVC?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 for the OS. MVC 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaaaaalright, it was actually all ok. The only thing is there was a directory empty in my scripts folder so it was not deployed... Unfortunately I had a rule with this directory in the pattern for making some bundles. SO it broke all others bundles.

Thanks @Vivien Chevallier for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Update your web.config, change the `<system.webServer>` section for the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="BundleModule" />
        <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Already try that and retried right now... But nothing. I've even done an iisreset to be sure but... nothing more.